# Is this a load bearing beam?

Tags: walls, construction, load-bearing, remodeling, architecture

Is the big steel beam running perpendicular to the joists a load bearing beam?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that would have been put there if it wasn't?

Comment: Just curious or is there something about this beam that requires your attention?

Comment: Thanks, on a typical house, how many of these do you see? Is it safe to say this is the only one, and the rest of walls are non-load bearing?

Comment: Nobody goes to the trouble and expense of putting steel in a house unless they need it to carry a big load over long, clear spans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gave me a chuckle. (*No offense intended*)

> Is the big steel beam running perpendicular to the joists a load
> bearing beam?

It is a beam and the photo shows a load on it, floor joists, and all of that on a post. So YES  it is load bearing beam.

I will leave it to others more knowledgeable and eloquent to explain further.

Comment: Thanks, I'm no construction guy, but that is what I guessed. So, is it safe to say that this is the only load bearing beam in the house? The reason I'm asking is because I had water damage and the water damage company cut the studs on a wall nearby. So I just want to make sure that they didn't destroy a load bearing wall

Comment: The presence of one beam is not an indicator of the number of other beams that may or may not be there. Beams and load bearing walls  may or may not  have  a relationship to each other. **If you have a question about weather or not a load bearing wall has been compromised you should post that as a separate question with as much detail as you can**.